# Export and import Test Results in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2010, I could able to export/import "test run result"

How can i do it in Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot export test results using VS2012 today. The available alternatives are a) copy-paste the content of the test explorer into notepad b) run your tests via vstest.console.exe on the commandline using the /logger:trx flag to generate a .trx file.

Once you have a .trx file it continues to be a valid file in VS and you will see your results in the Test Results window.